# Editing a value in array list

Tags: java, arraylist, edit

I'm trying to edit the values which are saved in an arraylist but i'm stuck up with the codes I can't proceed could u please help me with it.. 
The values in the array will be like 
Codes  Title       Prereq 
CS101  Computer    CS210
CS102  Process     CS211

Now I want to edit a particular course

```
    String code=request.getParameter("code");

    String title=request.getParameter("title");

    String preq=request.getParameter("preq");

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<prereqclass> prereqcl = (List<prereqclass>)request.getServletContext().getAttribute("Preqattr");

    for(prereqclass q:prereqcl){
        if(q.getCode()==code){

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when comparing Objects, use `.equals()` not `==`, as `==` will compare the Object's reference.

Second, by convention a `Class` should always start with an uppercase.

Then, I'm not sure which validation you want to do before editing and also which treatment as you are not specifying it.

Still, now that your

```
if(q.getCode()==code)
```

is modified to:

```
if(q.getCode().equals(code))
```

you will be able to enter the condition and modify your object using it's setter/getter methods.